# Mongoose querying an array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How to querying an array using Mongoose ?

search Schema:

```
const searchschema = new schema({
    yeardate: { type: Number, required: true, min: 1820 },
    word: { type: String, required: true, index: true },
    user: [{ type: schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]    })
```

user Schema:

```
const userschema = new schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, index: true },//
    name: { type: String, default: 'NoName' },
    gender: { type: String, default: 'male' },   })
```

This is the query I have tried but did not work:

```
searchmodel.paginate({ 'user': { $elemMatch: { gender: 'female' } } }, { page: page, limit: 5, populate: ['user'] }).then(searches => {
        if (!searches) {
            return res.json({ message: 'there is no search' })
        }else {
            return res.json(searches)
        }
    })
```

Comment: Can you elaborate in detail?

Comment: As per the documentation of paginate, you should use `populate:'user'`. You using `populate: ['user']`

Comment: @PrathameshMore I did, but it didn't make a difference .I want to find people whose gender is female(user.gender : 'female')

Comment: Can you post the error or output of code?

Comment: there is no error.result is empty @PrathameshMore